# Spring @Transactional with different Isolation levels from different call sources

Tags: java, sql, spring, transactions, deadlock

I want to use the same function in DAO, suppose `getBalances()` with secure `SERIALIZABLE` isolation:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public List<Balance> getBalances() { ... }
```

in important business logic method:

```
public doVeryImportantFinancialChanges() {
.. complicated logic with multiple getEntries() calls, multiple SELECT/UPDATE...
}
```

but also I want to have **unsafe** "life view" of balances called every 1-2 seconds with `SELECT` only and acceptable broken integrity and all those nonrepeatable, phantom etc. data.

The problem is that my "life view" scheduled `SELECT` requestor uses `getBalances()` highly isolated function, and gets:

`org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM ....]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction;`

**How to achieve double (safe-serializable and unsafe) access to same method getBalances() from different call sources?**

Comment: The service should be the transactional boundary, not your dao. Move the `@Transactional` with the proper configuration to the desired service method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)` on `getBalances` and define the isolation on the calling service.